# Beamer links of table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, links

can anyone explain me why, in a beamer presentation, when I click on a link in the table of contents I am always sent to the first frame of the whole presentation and not to the first frame of the corresponding section?

```
\section{name of section}
\begin{frame}{contents}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
```

Thanks in advance,
ph

Comment: Have you any MWE of that?

Comment: The default for an undefined link is the top of first page.

Comment: Ok but normally you shouldn't define the links position with the sections, isn't it?

Comment: I added a MWE but it isn't really helpful...but I am not looking for something special! There is something that can disturbs these kind of links (packages, commands or I don't know what..?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.